# .htaccess: something more than "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ..."

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have several domains for my page: https://www.mypage.es, https://www.mypage.it.... Now I'm trying to redirect just my french domain https://www.mypage.fr to https://www.mypage.com. So I have tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule https://www.mypage.fr$ https://www.mypage.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but doesn't work...

NOTE: This is working ok:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mypage.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Regards

Javi

Comment: You might want to clarify "doesn't work" -- is there an error in the log? is it redirecting to the wrong site? something else?

Comment: I mean it does not redirect to https://www.mypage.com

Comment: So what does it say in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mypage.fr$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mypage.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```